# Regex everything after the last instance of a word

Tags: regex, regex-negation

How can I get everything after the last 'foo' in a string with multiple foos?

Example of desired match in bold:

> This is a foo and another foo **end of story**

Answer (score 4):

You don't need any fancy lookarounds.

```
.*foo
```

matches up through the last `foo` because `.*` matches the longest possible string by definition, and just add `(.*)` to capture the text after it.

```
.*foo(.*)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
foo(?!.*foo)(.*)$
```

which looks for a `foo` not followed by another `foo` and then captures the characters after the last foo in group 1.

[Demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/YPYVBu/1/)

You may want to include word boundaries so as not to match e.g. `food`:

```
\bfoo\b(?!.*\bfoo\b)(.*)$
```

[Demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/YPYVBu/3/)

If you can use positive lookbehinds, you can make the whole regex match your desired string:

```
(?<=\bfoo\b)(?!.*\bfoo\b).*$
```

[Demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/YPYVBu/5)

Comment: I've clarified with the bolded example that I'd like to match everything without the last foo.

Comment: @AlexR if you look at the demos, the values you want are in capture group 1

Comment: Thanks, it looks like I've been ignoring capture groups, so it felt like I wasn't getting anywhere with previous solutions. Just out of curiosity, would you say that there are no solutions that don't involve extracting a capture group match?

Comment: @AlexR yes, it can be done, if you can use a positive lookbehind. See my edit.

Comment: Nice. I don't quite understand the logic of the combined positive and negative lookarounds in the last solution, but this is what I originally had in mind :)

Comment: Basically it is saying that at the start of the match, there *must* be the word `foo` immediately behind it (positive lookbehind), and there *must not* be the word `foo` somewhere ahead of it (negative lookahead).

Answer (score 0):

This expression might be an option for a full match with lookarounds:

```
(?:(?!(?<=(?=(?:.*)(?<=\bfoo\b)))).)+
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/oBQzaJ/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/oBQzaJ/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---